# How to properly use a 2-D array to store the results of split() of multiple strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, split

I am trying to write a loop that goes over several lines of text, splitting each line - each string - into two elements, with the result populating a two-dimensional array. I am currently getting a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` error with the code below, triggered on the `split()` line. I want to take the result of the `split()` call and use that with the rest of my program. Also, if I don't put an integer in the 2nd array box I get a compilation error - an argument is expected there.

```
String[][] arr = new String[numLines.size()][];

for(int i = 0 ; i < numLines.size(); i++) {
    arr[i][1].split("--", 2); 
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Are you initializing the rest of the 2-D array anywhere? From the code you're showing right now you've only got a 1-D array of null array pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to allocate the inner arrays yourself, `String.split()` does that for you. The reason you're getting the exception is that you're applying square brackets twice, i.e. you expect `arr[i]` to be a non-null array (and of size at least 2) so that you can assign to `arr[i][1]` - and that's not the case.

The thing is, you don't even *need* to use `arr[i][whatever]`. I think what you want to be doing is the following:

```
ArrayList<String> lines;

/*
 * you add your lines to the 'lines' here somehow.
 */

String[][] arr = new String[lines.size()][];

for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        arr[i] = lines.get(i).split("--", 2); 
        /* etc. */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's an issue with the definition of your array:

```
String[][] arr = new String[numLines.size()][];
```

The second dimention of your array is uninitialized. You can't access index `1` with your current setup. Try to load the array's data before trying to access it.

After defining it, you should populate it with (I presume) each "line" (whatever it is) from the data holder (say, a list, a reader, a file, you name it) that you get your `numLines` number from.

**Edit**

As einpoklum correctly spotted, the actual allocation of the array was done by the very `split()` method. Indeed, you were accessing a null reference

```
arr[i][1].split("--", 2); //NPE since arr[i] returns null
```

but the population was done on that same iteration (I'm taking ):

```
arr[i] = lines.get(i).split("--", 2);
```

Comment: Okay so I have an arraylist defined as `ArrayList<String> numLines` that I filled in my main function. So should I should define my 2nd dimension as lines?

Comment: @user2007843: I'm not sure Gamb's suggestion leads to an actual solution (unless I'm misreading what you intended to do.)